# Implementing Sales Funnel Reports

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

Is anyone aware of templates/documentation to implement a set of reports that can  can give information on Leads and Opportunities that move through the Sales Funnel e.g.

Inquiry - Marketing Qualification - Sales Qualification.

What I would be looking for is for `numbers/volumes (% drop off) and velocity` at each stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achievable. Approach will be as follows

1. Create a matrix report.
2. Create Bucket field for Stages (Inquiry, Marketing Qualification, Sales Qualification) and name it as `different stages`
3. Create Summary formula naming `%drop off`, specify row/column grouping level as `Owner` and `different stages`

   formula will look like this:

   `RowCount/PARENTGROUPVAL(RowCount, OWNER, COLUMN_GRAND_SUMMARY)`
4. Finally, put column grouping as `different stages` and row grouping as `Owner`.

I have used this kind of concepts in one of our case reports where cases has been grouped into duration by case owners with %issue closed.

[image: case reports]

Refer [Getting Started With Buckets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dq1TkYzT-mM)

Refer video: [Hands-on Training: Compare Report Groupings with Summary Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9c1_ErEtCf0)

Comment: Thanks for this. Would there be any way to get leads and opportunities on the same report? I suppose a joined report is the best we would be able to do.